# SVG Dashed line for circle created with path

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have the following issue. I have to draw a circle from a lot of points which are too close enough. You could see it in the jsfiddle link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/L6e5oz3L/

```
<path style="" stroke-dasharray="10 5" fill="#0000ff" stroke="#0000ff" d="M181.8181818181818,225L181.8181818181818,225M181.8181818181818,225L181.7933822865362....
```

I am using path for the case. Now I have to put stroke-dasharray style on it but actually the points are too close and the dashes are not rendered as expected here:

[image]

Do you have some ideas how could I achieve that effect?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Why not use a `<circle>`?

Comment: Like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/L6e5oz3L/1/

Comment: Simplify the path to a circle like path eg: `d="M50,100a50,50 0 1,0 100,0a50,50 0 1,0 -100,0"`

Comment: The issue is that the dashed line is rendered between two points, so when they are too close - it's not rendered as a dashed lines for the whole path but for between separate two points and actually it looks like a continuous line. I don't have the option to create a circle. Maybe I could put some algorithm for divide the line as dashed lines?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter if it's circle or just a path. The points are too close enough to be no able to rendered the dotted lines or dashes. Do you have an idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it - if I use polyline instead of path with fill color "none", It works perfectly.